# SQL - How can I change this code of left outer join to right outer join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this following SQL code which needs to be converted to right outer join. As I'm still on the learning path of SQL, can I simply change LEFT JOIN to RIGHT JOIN?

```
SELECT message, count(comment_likes.id) AS total_likes
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN comment_likes ON comment_id = comments.id
GROUP BY message
ORDER BY total_likes DESC
```

Comment: Welcome to the last time you will ever use RIGHT JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just reverse the tables:

```
SELECT message, count(comment_likes.id) AS total_likes
FROM comment_likes RIGHT JOIN
     comments
     ON comment_id = comments.id
GROUP BY message
ORDER BY total_likes DESC;
```

That said, I (and others) have a strong preference for `LEFT JOIN` because it says "keep everything in the table you just saw" rather than "keep everything in some table that you will eventually see as you read the `FROM` clause".